# Which grease should I use on wiper mechanisms?

Tags: windshield-wipers, lubrication, grease

The front wiper mechanism on my 1988 Porsche 944 has become a bit slow moving and I plan to fix it. On my car the wiper crank arms go through sockets in a frame, the crank arms are moved back and forth by linkages attached to a motor.

I plan to remove the whole frame from the car, remove the retainer clips holding the crank arms, clean the sockets and arms, grease them, and then re-assemble. I'm not sure what grease is best to use for this application, I have silicone, lithium-12 and copper grease available.

Here's a [image: schematic of the part], see the red circle for the particular problem point.

I plan to use silicone on the linkages (3 and 5 on the schematic) and where they pop onto the crank arms.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a picture?

Comment: My wiper assembly is under a plastic cover, I won't be able to provide a picture of it, I have found a schematic though, and I'll add on edit

Comment: I did a similar operation and you might want to replace the linkages while you are in there.  They wear out, and getting the wiper transmission out is such a PITA you don't want to do it twice :-)

Comment: That's a good point @Ukko, and I'm already there - they are in a box and ready to go.

Comment: @GdD good to hear, I usually have to order the box after I get the parts taken out.

Comment: Well, when I got the car I saw one of the linkages was getting loose so harnessed the power of the internet.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I have not used copper grease on any brake applications for the reasons stated above, even though quite a few people who should know better still recommend using it. The best grease currently available for brakes is Ceramic grease due to its high temperature and high pressure resistance. For these reasons I think it would also be very suitable for wiper linkages. Possibly also consider boat trailer hub grease as it is designed for damp conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the lithium or silicone grease!

Copper grease is primarily used to prevent the seizing of parts which become extremely hot, like the exhaust system. But it is not a lubricant in first place. The grease bounds the copper powder, but isn't made for lubrication, an copper powder in a moving bearing can't be good, even though copper is a rather soft metal. Initially, the grease can prevent corrosion, but when it vanishes, the copper can cause even more corrosion, depending on the other materials. This is one reason why copper grease should not be used for the brakes.

Silicone grease has several advantages: Its viscosity is constant over a vast temperature range, it usually does not harm any rubber / plastic, it doesn't age and so on. But its lubrication performance is not as high as people often think, and it's expensive.

Mineral oil based greases have the best lubrication performance and are cheaper than silicone.

(This is of course just a generic description. There are thousands of lubricants out there with many different properties, all made for special use cases.)